# Prevent double execution of a jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I've set up the this function to show one div at a time that has been targeted in the navigation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div1, .div2').hide();
    $("nav a").hover(function () {  
    var name= this.name;
    $("."+name).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
   });  
});
```

This function works, but if I'm switching very fast beteween my nav element it can happen that div1 and div2 appear at the same time.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the existing animation before hiding.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div1, .div2').hide();
    $("nav a").hover(function () {  
    var name= this.name;
    $("."+name).fadeIn().siblings().stop(true, true).hide();
   });  
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Such an elegeant and easy solution. Very good to know for future scripts. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, I just recognized that the animation stops at one point if I'm switching to fast and a div might stop at half opacity and doesn't recover. How comes that? Might rewriting the script a solid solution?

Comment: Did you try passing `true` as the second parameter to `stop`, as per the documentation?

Comment: Now it works like charm! Thank you a very lot for the second run! :)